# Betti numbers of associated graded ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a (not necessarily commutative) local ring with commutative residue field $k$. Define it's betti numbers as
$$\beta_i(R):=\dim_k\mathrm{Tor}^i_R(k,k).$$

The associated graded ring

$$\mathrm{gr}(R)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}, $$
is also a local ring with residue field $k$. One can easily see that for $i=0,1$, we have
$$\beta_i(R)=\beta_i(\mathrm{gr}(R)).$$

Is there any connection between the betti numbers $\beta_i(R)$ and $\beta_i(\mathrm{gr}(R))$ for $i\geq 2$?

Comment: In the commutative case, the Betti numbers of the ring are smaller than or equal to the Betti numbers of the associated graded ring. This fact follows from a more general result due to Robbiano, but you may find a proof in Corollary 3.2 of the paper "On the depth of the symmetric algebra" by Herzog, Rossi, and Valla. If they are all equal, the ring is said to be of homogeneous type.

Comment: @Francesco Thank you, that is very useful. Can you tell me the name of the reference by Robbiano

Comment: @Francesco I also skipped over the proof of Corollary 3.2 and it seems to generalize to non-commutative rings.

Comment: Perhaps the alternating sums of the Betti numbers must agree (assuming those sums are defined). I would expect there to be a spectral sequence starting with Tor over the associated graded and converging to Tor over $R$, which might account for lowering the Betti numbers as you pass from the associated graded to $R$, and also for the alternating sums matching up.

Comment: Robbiano's paper is cited in the above paper, but it is in italian

Comment: @JohnPalmieri in the paper mentioned by Francesco they prove that the alternating numbers (Euler-Characteristic) indeed agree